# What's blocking "Select top 1 * from TableName with (nolock)" from returning a result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, locking

I'm currently running the following statement

```
select * into adhoc..san_savedi from dps_san..savedi_record
```

It's taking a painfully long time and I'd like to see how far along it is so I ran this:

```
select count(*) from adhoc..san_savedi with (nolock)
```

That didn't return anything in a timely manner so for the heck of it I did this:

```
select top 1 * from adhoc..san_savedi with (nolock)
```

Even that seems to run indefinitely.  I could understand if there are millions of records that the count(*) could take a long time, but I don't understand why selecting the top 1 record wouldn't come back pretty much immediately considering I specified nolock.

In the name of full disclosure, dps_san is a view that pulls from an odbc connection via linked server.  I don't think that'd be affecting why I can't return the top row but just throwing it out there in case I'm wrong.

So I want to know what is keeping that statement from running?

EDIT:

As I mentioned above, yes dps_san..savedi_record is a view.  Here's what it does:

```
select * from DPS_SAN..root.SAVEDI_RECORD
```

It's nothing more than an alias and does no grouping/sorting/etc so I don't think the problem lies here, but please enlighten me if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: What does the view do?  If it performs GROUP BYs, ORDER BYs or uses aggregate functions then it could be that selecting the top 1 row is nearly as expensive as selecting all of them.

Comment: Are you sure the SELECT INTO has written a single row to disk yet? Maybe it's still in schema lock mode because it's still waiting for ODBC to deliver the first row from your linked connection.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, I'm not sure.  However, I can open up another query window and select records from dps_san..savedi_record all I want and get results so it would be odd if it hadn't written any results by now (it's been 2+ hours).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SELECT` queries with `NOLOCK` don't actually take no locks, they still need a `SCH-S` (schema stability) lock on the table ([and as it is a heap it will also take a `hobt` lock](http://tenbulls.co.uk/2011/10/14/nolock-hits-mythbusters/)).

Additionally before the `SELECT` can even begin SQL Server must compile a plan for the statement, which also requires it to take a `SCH-S` lock out on the table.

As your long running transaction creates the table via `SELECT ... INTO` it holds an incompatible `SCH-M` lock on it until the statement completes.

You can verify this by looking in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` <strike>whilst</strike> <strike>while</strike> during the period of blocking.

When I tried the following in one connection

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT *
INTO NewT
FROM master..spt_values

/*Remember to rollback/commit this later*/
```

And then executing (or just simply trying to view the estimated execution plan)

```
SELECT *
FROM NewT
WITH (NOLOCK)
```

in a second the reading query was blocked.

```
SELECT wait_type,
       resource_description
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
WHERE session_id = <spid_of_waiting_task>
```

Shows the wait type is indeed `SCH_S` and the blocking resource `SCH-M`

```
wait_type        resource_description
---------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LCK_M_SCH_S      objectlock lockPartition=0 objid=461960722 subresource=FULL dbid=1 id=lock4a8a540 mode=Sch-M associatedObjectId=461960722
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks, think "whilst" is OK for Brits to use [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While)!

Comment: That doesn't mean I have to like it. Brits can also use "while" right? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Actually while does sound better to me as well. I plan to extend my answer so I'll revisit that at the same time!

Comment: Just giving you a hard time man. I have an opinion about whilst but it doesn't prevent me from understanding you. :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith Your answer is good, but I really only gave you a +1 for the use the word whilst.

Comment: @BrandonMoore - Ha Ha! What a dilemma.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, and because you share the name of one of my all time favorite musicians :)

Comment: You know, it just ocurred to me that (no lock) probably isn't even doing anything anyway since the target db isn't sql server and quite likely not even a fully sql compliant database.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I also understand that NOLOCK on a table without clustered index (heap) will result in S lock on the JOBTT (entire table), thereby blocking writes - can you comment on this please?

Answer (score 2):

It very well may be that there are no locks... If dps_san..savedi_record is a view, then it may be taking a long time to execute, because it may be accessing tables without using an index, or it may be sorting millions of records, or whatever reason. Then your query, even a simple top or count, will be only as fast as that view can be executed.

Comment: The select is against a table that is being populated, not a view.

Comment: See my edit.  The view just selects *.  No grouping/sorting/or anything that would cause it to need to scan the entire table before returning results or anything like that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I figured he was saying the same thing you suggested, that it may not have gotten around to inserting any records yet.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues to consider here. Is dps_san..savedi_record a view? If so, it could just be taking a really long time to get your data. The other thing I can think of is that you're trying to create a temp table by using the `select into` syntax, which is a bad idea. `select * into ...` syntax will lock the tempdb for duration of the select.

If you are creating the table using that syntax, then there is a workaround. First, create the table by throwing `where 1=0` at the end of your initial statement:

```
select * into ... from ... where 1=0
```

This will create the table first (which is quick) which allows you to `insert into` because the table exists now (without penalty of locking tempdb for duration of query).

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are correct sir, thank you for fixing that for me (forgot it can only be used to create table). [Select Into... Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Find the `session_id` that is performing the `select into`:

```
SELECT r.session_id, r.blocking_session_id, r.wait_type, r.wait_time
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.plan_handle) AS t
  WHERE t.[text] LIKE '%select%into%adhoc..san_savedi%';
```

This should let you know if another session is blocking the select into or if it has a wait type that is causing a problem.

You can repeat the process in another window for the session that is trying to do the select. I suspect Martin is right and that my earlier comment about schema lock is relevant.

Comment: s's are supposed to be r's I assume.

Comment: NOLOCK on heap (table without clustered index) results in S lock on HOBT thereby blocking any writes on the table - can you comment on this please?