# How to SELECT COUNT from tables currently being INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi consider there is an INSERT statement running on a table TABLE_A, which takes a long time, I would like to see how has it progressed.

What I tried was to open up a new session (new query window in SSMS) while the long running statement is still in process, I ran the query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE_A WITH (nolock)
```

hoping that it will return right away with the number of rows everytime I run the query, but the test result was even with (nolock), still, it only returns after the INSERT statement is completed.

What have I missed? Do I add (nolock) to the INSERT statement as well? Or is this not achievable?

---

(Edit)
OK, I have found what I missed. If you first use CREATE TABLE TABLE_A, then INSERT INTO TABLE_A, the SELECT COUNT will work. If you use SELECT * INTO TABLE_A FROM xxx, without first creating TABLE_A, then non of the following will work (not even sysindexes).

Comment: A single INSERT is an atomic statement. It has either inserted all the rows or none. There is no count available from the middle of the transaction.

Comment: what i know about With (Nolock) is, it returns the snapshot taken before locking the table for DML statements. So until DML finished, it won't return latest result.

Comment: Use TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL for such scenarios.

Comment: You can use SSIS to do the copy, and use bulk insert,you can configure the batch size and you will see the rows being transfered by batchs. (It will only be na atomic statement for the batch that fails, rows already inserted will remain in the table)

Comment: @AshimDas This will not help get a progressive count of how many rows have been inserted.

Comment: If you have rough idea how much work the insert does, you could get some kind of idea from logical reads in sys.dm_exec_requests. There is also percent complete there but it won't help you :)

Comment: @DavidG, you are correct. TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL will not work. I tried the same.

Comment: DO NOT EVER use NOLOCK on an insert. This is one of the very absolute always things in sql server. Using NOLOCK when inserting, updating or deleting is no go at any time, there really are no exception to this. It can corrupt your indexes and cause all sort of issues.

Comment: What was the context of the `insert`? Was it wrapped in a `transaction` and/or sourced from a `select`? Because there are proofs below that one _can_ obtain a partial `count` from certain in-progress `insert`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 the [live query statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn831878.aspx) feature can allow you to see the progress of the insert in real time.

The below screenshot was taken while inserting 10 million rows into a table with a clustered index and a single nonclustered index.

It shows that the insert was 88% complete on the clustered index and this will be followed by a sort operator to get the values into non clustered index key order before inserting into the NCI. This is a blocking operator and the sort cannot output any rows until all input rows are consumed so the operators to the left of this are 0% done.

[image]

With respect to your question on `NOLOCK`

It is trivial to test

### Connection 1

```
USE tempdb

CREATE TABLE T2
  (
     X INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     F CHAR(8000)
  );

WHILE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM   T2 WITH (NOLOCK))
  LOOP:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountMethod FROM   T2 WITH (NOLOCK);

SELECT rows FROM   sysindexes WHERE  id = OBJECT_ID('T2');

RAISERROR ('Waiting for 10 seconds',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;

WAITFOR delay '00:00:10';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountMethod FROM   T2 WITH (NOLOCK);

SELECT rows FROM   sysindexes WHERE  id = OBJECT_ID('T2');

RAISERROR ('Waiting to drop table',0,1) WITH NOWAIT

DROP TABLE T2
```

### Connection 2

```
use tempdb;

--Insert 2000 * 2000 = 4 million rows
WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP 2000 'x' AS x
         FROM   master..spt_values)
INSERT INTO T2
            (F)
SELECT 'X'
FROM   T v1
       CROSS JOIN T v2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

### Example Results - Showing row count increasing

[image]

`SELECT` queries with `NOLOCK` allow dirty reads. They don't actually take no locks and can still be blocked, they still need a `SCH-S` (schema stability) lock on the table ([and on a heap it will also take a `hobt` lock](http://tenbulls.co.uk/2011/10/14/nolock-hits-mythbusters/)).

The only thing incompatible with a `SCH-S` is a `SCH-M` (schema modification) lock. Presumably you also performed some DDL on the table in the same transaction (e.g. perhaps created it in the same tran)

For the use case of a large insert, where an approximate in flight result is fine, I generally just poll `sysindexes` as shown above to retrieve the count from metadata rather than actually counting the rows ([non deprecated alternative DMVs are available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martijnh/archive/2010/07/15/sql-server-how-to-quickly-retrieve-accurate-row-count-for-table.aspx))

When an insert has a [wide update plan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/07/27/wide-vs-narrow-plans.aspx) you can even see it inserting to the various indexes in turn that way.

If the table is created inside the inserting transaction this `sysindexes` query will still block though as the `OBJECT_ID` function won't return a result based on uncommitted data regardless of the isolation level in effect. It's sometimes possible to get around that by getting the object_id from `sys.tables` with `nolock` instead.

Comment: Isn't your conn1 doing the `insert` _then_ waiting, meaning that the count from conn2 is both expected and irrelevant to the OP? I don't know the finer points of `insert` vs `transaction` when it comes to locking though, so I welcome education!

Comment: You may be correct, but your test is not accurate. Adding a `WAITFOR` isn't the same thing as trying to read the values mid-INSERT. It's entirely possible it produces the same result but I'm not so sure (can't test here at the moment as I'm not in reach of a SQL Server to play with)

Comment: @underscore_d - Only because it makes for an easier demo. The argument in the other answers is that it is not possible because it would violate ACID. There is no difference in ACID properties between a single statement in an autocommit transaction and an explicit tran. I would certainly be able to produce an example of a single statement with the same behaviour.

Comment: Ah well, like @davidg, I'll be interested to test this once I'm back at my desk.

Comment: +1. in the meantime i also found another supporting discussion: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/44243/get-count-while-insert-is-still-running.html thanks for the lesson!

Comment: Thanks heaps! In my case the SELECT COUNT still doesn't return or it takes a long time to count and the INSERT has already completed. What is working for me is the sysindexes, it returns right away. But what is sad is I can't filter on WHERE clause if my table contains other records before my INSERT if I am using sysindexes for the rows...its really give and take.

Comment: @user1589188 - From the edit to your question you are using `SELECT ... INTO`. That will maintain a `SCH-M` lock blocking everything [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955964/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the clarification, very nice indeed.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer**: You can't do this.

**Longer answer**: A single INSERT statement is an [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) operation. As such, the query has either inserted all the rows or has inserted none of them. Therefore you can't get a count of how far through it has progressed.

**Even longer answer**: Martin Smith has given you a way to achieve what you want. Whether you still want to do it that way is up to you of course. Personally I still prefer to insert in manageable batches if you really need to track progress of something like this. So I would rewrite the INSERT as multiple smaller statements. Depending on your implementation, that may be a trivial thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, thats good to know. But thats really counter intuitive when you consider when an atomic operation is taking so long to complete, it must be doing things slowly chunk by chunk...and still there is no way to see whats going on there.

Comment: Well possibly, depends on your point of view. But being able to determine progress would violate atomicity rules. By the way, you almost certainly don't want to use a cursor, they can be very slow and impact performance if used badly. Can you not do the inserts in batches, 100 or 100 records at a time?

Comment: Hummm, I guess I shall try doing it in batches, but the issue is some of the INSERTs I have can do avg. 1000 rec/s but some is like 5 rec/s. In order to determine the good batch size, I will have to test each INSERT and do a CASE, which is not something I want.

Comment: 5 INSERTs per second seems extremely slow, unless the data is many megabytes, this looks like a performance issue.

Comment: My INSERTs include reading files like Excel using OPENROWSET, I guess thats why.

Comment: That shouldn't really be slowing down the INSERT, though it may take a while to start going.

Comment: Think about what you expect the NOLOCK statement to actually do. If every statement is unavoidably atomic, then NOLOCK couldn't possibly have any effect on the result, making it a useless part of the SQL language. For example there is data shearing, where if two transactions modify the same two rows, you can in rare cases see one row from transaction A and one from transaction B. Of course this does not happen if you stick to default isolation levels and only do basic queries, so no need to be too worried. But atomicity is more like an opt-out thing than an absolute fact.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query to find the count for any large table or locked table or being inserted table in seconds . Just replace the table name which you want to search.

```
SELECT
   Total_Rows= SUM(st.row_count)
FROM
   sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE
    object_name(object_id) = 'TABLENAME' AND (index_id < 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who just need to see the record count while executing a long running INSERT script, I found you can see the current record count through SSMS by right clicking on the destination database table, -> Properties -> Storage, then view the "Row Count" value like so:

[image]

Close window and repeat to see the updated record count.